# Laravel : save radio group with difference key

Tags: laravel, radio-group

I want to save radios group in database with different question_id

I tried to use form with radio's input have name=answer

controller :

```
public function store(Request $request, Survey $survey)
    {   
        $question = \App\Question::where('survey_id', '=' , $survey->id)->get();
        $request->validate([
            'answer'=>'required'
          ]);
         $arr = $request->except('_token');
          $newAnswer = new Answer();
          $newAnswer->answer = request()->get('answer');
          foreach ($survey->questions as $key=>$question){
            $newAnswer->question_id = $question->id;
          }
          $newAnswer->user_id = Auth::id();
          $newAnswer->last_ip = request()->ip();
          $newAnswer->survey_id = $survey->id;
          $newAnswer->commentaire = request()->get('commentaire');
          givePoint(new VoteAdded($newAnswer));
          $newAnswer->save(); 

          return redirect()->action('SurveyController@view_survey_answers', [$survey->id]);
    }
```

view :

```
<div id="Create" class="col-12" style="display:none;">             
         {!! Form::open(array('action'=>array('AnswerController@store', $survey->id))) !!}
         <div class="text-center">
         <img class="rounded"
         src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/grapefruit-slice-332-332.jpg"
         alt="Grapefruit slice atop a pile of other slices" />
         </div>
         <hr>
          @foreach ($survey->questions as $question)

            <p class="flow-text">Question {{ $zero++}} - {{ $question->title }}</p>
                @if($question->question_type === 'text')
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <input id="answer" type="text" name="answer">
                    <label for="answer">Answer</label>
                  </div> 
                </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'textarea')
                <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                  <div class="input-field col s12">
                    <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" name="{{ $question->id }}[answer]"></textarea>
                    <label for="textarea1">Textarea</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'radio')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                    <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      @if($value === 'else')
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <input name="answer" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="{{ $value }}" value="{{$value}}"/>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                        <div id="textboxes" style="display: none">
                            <br>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="commentaire" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Write a large text here ..."></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div> 
                        @else
                      <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                        <input name="answer[{{$question->id}}]" class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="{{ $value }}" value="{{ $value}}"/>
                        <label class="custom-control-label" for="{{ $value }}">{{ $value }}</label>
                        </div>
                    </p>
                        @endif
                  @endforeach
                @elseif($question->question_type === 'checkbox')
                  @foreach($question->option_name as $key=>$value)
                  <p style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="checkbox" id="{{ $value }}" name="answer" value="{{$value}}"/>
                      <label for="{{$value}}">{{ $value }}</label>
                      </div>
                  </p>
                  @endforeach
                @endif 
              <div class="divider" style="margin:10px 10px;"></div>
              @endforeach
          <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Submit Survey', array('class'=>'btn btn-success mt-4')) }}
          </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}

                 </div>
```

Tables :
i have already made it :

- Answer table = id, survey_id , question_id , answer . commentaire ,
  timestamp
- Survey table : id title ...
- question table : id , suvey_id , option_type , options

I got in my database a array: ["question_id" = "value"] 
what a want is for example i have 2 questions , in my database i want to save 2 row with some survey id but different question id

could you help me to do that ?

Comment: If you need more data like model ... please write me a commentaire and thanks

Answer (score 0):

-Since 1 survey can have many questions create a separate table for questions like survey_questions
-You can insert in multiple tables at the same time by writing insert queries for the survey and survey questions table separately and wrapping it in a transaction. In Laravel, you can do something like

```
try{
    DB::transaction();
    //insert in survey table
    //insert in survey questions table
    DB::commit();
} catch(\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback()
}
```

Comment: i have already made it :
- Answer table = id, survey_id , question_id , answer . commentaire , timestamp
- Survey table : id title ...
- question table : id , suvey_id , option_type , options

Comment: You want to insert records in all 3 tables simultaneously right?

Comment: no only in answer , multi question with differente radio group , i want to record like that : answer with survey's id and question id for example i have survey with 2 questions i want to have in my db 2 lines same survey id and question_id is question's id and survey id